# SFTP streaming failing with status code 4 for different users on the same sever

Tags: node.js, ssh, stream, sftp

**Issue**
I am using ssh2 (by utilising the nodeSSH wrapper) for connecting to SFTP servers and downloading the files from SFTP server to Amazon S3.

I have a SFTP server (don't know how it is setup as it is a third party managed and I only have credentials and list of permissions for files/folders). I am trying to upload the files from SFTP server to s3 by streaming it directly to s3. For this I am creating a SFTP channel by using requestSFTP method and then creating a read stream using it and then simply pass the stream to s3.

I have two users on this server which have identical permissions for files/directory (full access for sftp user, rwx). For one user, the streaming operation works as expected and file is successfully streamed to s3. For another user, I am constantly getting SFTP: Inbound: Received STATUS (id:3, 4, "Failure.").

The NodeSSH shouldn't be an issue as I have tried using other SFTP clients and it is still getting the same issue.

**Things I have tried**

I have tried to download the files using fastGet method instead of streaming and files for both users are downloaded successfully. I have also tried the solution for different node-versions like 14.x, 16.x but getting the same error.

I have collected the verbose logs and the only difference is status of SFTP: Inbound: Received STATUS. In successful case, it is getting status code 3 but in failure it is getting status code 4.

I tried to find more details on this status code but looks like it is kind of 5xx for SFTP protocol.

Logs for successful file streaming: (changed host to dummy host)

```
using new version
using stream
testing stream
Custom crypto binding not available
Local ident: 'SSH-2.0-ssh2js1.14.0'
Client: Trying x.x.x.x on port 5151 ...
Socket connected
Remote ident: 'SSH-2.0-Serv-U_15.3.0.1356'
Outbound: Sending KEXINIT
Inbound: Handshake in progress
Handshake: (local) KEX method: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,curve25519-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group15-sha512,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group17-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,ext-info-c
Handshake: (remote) KEX method: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
Handshake: KEX algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
Handshake: (local) Host key format: ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
Handshake: (remote) Host key format: ssh-rsa
Handshake: Host key format: ssh-rsa
Handshake: (local) C->S cipher: aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
Handshake: (remote) C->S cipher: aes128-cbc,rijndael128-cbc,aes192-cbc,rijndael192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
Handshake: C->S Cipher: aes128-ctr
Handshake: (local) S->C cipher: aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
Handshake: (remote) S->C cipher: aes128-cbc,rijndael128-cbc,aes192-cbc,rijndael192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
Handshake: S->C cipher: aes128-ctr
Handshake: (local) C->S MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
Handshake: (remote) C->S MAC: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96
Handshake: C->S MAC: hmac-sha2-256
Handshake: (local) S->C MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
Handshake: (remote) S->C MAC: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96
Handshake: S->C MAC: hmac-sha2-256
Handshake: (local) C->S compression: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
Handshake: (remote) C->S compression: zlib,none
Handshake: C->S compression: none
Handshake: (local) S->C compression: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
Handshake: (remote) S->C compression: zlib,none
Handshake: S->C compression: none
Outbound: Sending KEXECDH_INIT
Received DH Reply
Host accepted by default (no verification)
Host accepted (verified)
Outbound: Sending NEWKEYS
Inbound: NEWKEYS
Verifying signature ...
Verified signature
Handshake completed
Outbound: Sending SERVICE_REQUEST (ssh-userauth)
Inbound: Received SERVICE_ACCEPT (ssh-userauth)
Outbound: Sending USERAUTH_REQUEST (none)
Inbound: Received USERAUTH_FAILURE (password)
Client: none auth failed
Outbound: Sending USERAUTH_REQUEST (password)
Inbound: Received USERAUTH_SUCCESS
connected
Outbound: Sending CHANNEL_OPEN (r:0, session)
Inbound: CHANNEL_OPEN_CONFIRMATION (r:0, s:0)
Outbound: Sending CHANNEL_REQUEST (r:0, subsystem: sftp)
Inbound: CHANNEL_SUCCESS (r:0)
Outbound: Sending CHANNEL_DATA (r:0, 9)
Inbound: CHANNEL_DATA (r:0, 9)
SFTP: Inbound: Received VERSION (v3)
Outbound: Sending CHANNEL_DATA (r:0, 57)
SFTP: Outbound: Buffered OPEN
Inbound: CHANNEL_DATA (r:0, 21)
SFTP: Inbound: Received HANDLE (id:0)
Outbound: Sending CHANNEL_DATA (r:0, 33)
SFTP: Outbound: Buffered READ
Inbound: CHANNEL_DATA (r:0, 196)
SFTP: Inbound: Received DATA (id:1, 183)
Outbound: Sending CHANNEL_DATA (r:0, 33)
SFTP: Outbound: Buffered READ
data event ----------- data length 183
Inbound: CHANNEL_DATA (r:0, 35)
SFTP: Inbound: Received STATUS (id:2, 1, "End of file.")
Outbound: Sending CHANNEL_DATA (r:0, 21)
SFTP: Outbound: Buffered CLOSE
Inbound: CHANNEL_DATA (r:0, 31)
SFTP: Inbound: Received STATUS (id:3, 0, "Success.")
close event --------
Outbound: Sending DISCONNECT (11)
Socket ended
Socket closed
Logs for unsuccessful file
```

```
using new version
using stream
testing stream
Custom crypto binding not available
Local ident: 'SSH-2.0-ssh2js1.14.0'
Client: Trying x.x.x.x on port 5151 ...
Socket connected
Remote ident: 'SSH-2.0-Serv-U_15.3.0.1356'
Outbound: Sending KEXINIT
Inbound: Handshake in progress
Handshake: (local) KEX method: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,curve25519-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group15-sha512,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group17-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,ext-info-c
Handshake: (remote) KEX method: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
Handshake: KEX algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
Handshake: (local) Host key format: ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
Handshake: (remote) Host key format: ssh-rsa
Handshake: Host key format: ssh-rsa
Handshake: (local) C->S cipher: aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
Handshake: (remote) C->S cipher: aes128-cbc,rijndael128-cbc,aes192-cbc,rijndael192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
Handshake: C->S Cipher: aes128-ctr
Handshake: (local) S->C cipher: aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
Handshake: (remote) S->C cipher: aes128-cbc,rijndael128-cbc,aes192-cbc,rijndael192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
Handshake: S->C cipher: aes128-ctr
Handshake: (local) C->S MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
Handshake: (remote) C->S MAC: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96
Handshake: C->S MAC: hmac-sha2-256
Handshake: (local) S->C MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
Handshake: (remote) S->C MAC: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96
Handshake: S->C MAC: hmac-sha2-256
Handshake: (local) C->S compression: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
Handshake: (remote) C->S compression: zlib,none
Handshake: C->S compression: none
Handshake: (local) S->C compression: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
Handshake: (remote) S->C compression: zlib,none
Handshake: S->C compression: none
Outbound: Sending KEXECDH_INIT
Received DH Reply
Host accepted by default (no verification)
Host accepted (verified)
Outbound: Sending NEWKEYS
Inbound: NEWKEYS
Verifying signature ...
Verified signature
Handshake completed
Outbound: Sending SERVICE_REQUEST (ssh-userauth)
Inbound: Received SERVICE_ACCEPT (ssh-userauth)
Outbound: Sending USERAUTH_REQUEST (none)
Inbound: Received USERAUTH_FAILURE (password)
Client: none auth failed
Outbound: Sending USERAUTH_REQUEST (password)
Inbound: Received USERAUTH_SUCCESS
connected
Outbound: Sending CHANNEL_OPEN (r:0, session)
Inbound: CHANNEL_OPEN_CONFIRMATION (r:0, s:0)
Outbound: Sending CHANNEL_REQUEST (r:0, subsystem: sftp)
Inbound: CHANNEL_SUCCESS (r:0)
Outbound: Sending CHANNEL_DATA (r:0, 9)
Inbound: CHANNEL_DATA (r:0, 9)
SFTP: Inbound: Received VERSION (v3)
Outbound: Sending CHANNEL_DATA (r:0, 97)
SFTP: Outbound: Buffered OPEN
Inbound: CHANNEL_DATA (r:0, 21)
SFTP: Inbound: Received HANDLE (id:0)
Outbound: Sending CHANNEL_DATA (r:0, 33)
SFTP: Outbound: Buffered READ
Inbound: CHANNEL_DATA (r:0, 19591)
SFTP: Inbound: Received DATA (id:1, 19578)
Outbound: Sending CHANNEL_DATA (r:0, 33)
SFTP: Outbound: Buffered READ
data event ----------- data length 19578
Inbound: CHANNEL_DATA (r:0, 35)
SFTP: Inbound: Received STATUS (id:2, 1, "End of file.")
Outbound: Sending CHANNEL_DATA (r:0, 21)
SFTP: Outbound: Buffered CLOSE
Inbound: CHANNEL_DATA (r:0, 31)
SFTP: Inbound: Received STATUS (id:3, 4, "Failure.")
```

I tried to find out more details about these errors in the SSH2 codebase but it is beyond my understanding. What configurations I should change on the server side or client side to resolve this issue?